# Dataframe's with strange structure with variables in even columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm a beginner with python in combination with pandas, and I understand the basics.
But I received a couple days ago 3 strange datasets in excel.
As image below:
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

dfinput = pd.DataFrame([
    ["uuid", "79876081-099b-474f-9e8f-ff917fd7394c", "uuid", "a96bc7cb-02b1-4d13-823a-908531cda095", "uuid",
        "38bc7d20-10be-4774-973c-b3b00234a645", "uuid", "e7b12da6-a47f-4c24-8545-faa24e249a03", "uuid", "6b2c9426-bd6f-4bda-9c53-a86200e051f8"],
    ["variable 1", "value", "variable 1", "value", "variable 1",
        "value", "variable 1", "value", "variable 1", "value"],
    ["variable 2", "value", "variable 2", "value", "variable 2",
        "value", "variable 2", "value", "variable 2", "value"],
    ["variable 3", "value", "variable 3", "value", "variable 3",
        "value", "variable 3", "value", "variable 3", "value"],
    ["variable 4", "value", "variable 4", "value", "variable 4",
        "value", "variable 4", "value", "variable 4", "value"],
    ["variable 5", "value", "variable 5", "value", "variable 5",
        "value", "variable 5", "value", "variable 5", "value"],
    ["variable 6", "value", "variable 6", "value", "variable 6",
        "value", "variable 6", "value", "variable 6", "value"],
    ["variable 7", "value", "variable 7", "value", "variable 7",
        "value", "variable 7", "value", "variable 7", "value"],
    ["variable 8", "value", "variable 8", "value", "variable 8",
        "value", "variable 8", "value", "variable 8", "value"],
    ["variable 9", "value", "variable 9", "value", "variable 9",
        "value", "variable 9", "value", "variable 9", "value"],
    ["variable 10", "value", "variable 10", "value", "variable 10",
        "value", "variable 10", "value", "variable 10", "value"],
    ["variable A", "value", "variable B", "value", "variable A",
        "value", "variable A", "value", "variable A", "value"],
    ["variable B", "value", "variable C", "value", "variable C",
        "value", "variable B", "value", "variable B", "value"],
    ["variable C", "value", "variable D", "value", "variable D",
        "value", "variable D", "value", "variable C", "value"],
    ["variable D", "value", "Variable E", "value", "Variable E",
        "value", "Variable F", "value", "Variable E", "value"],
    ["Variable E", "value", "Variable F", "value", "Variable H",
        "value", "Variable G", "value", "Variable F", "value"],
    ["Variable F", "value", "Variable H", "value", "",
        "", "Variable H", "value", "Variable G", "value"],
    ["Variable G", "value", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Variable H", "value"]
])
```

I want the following result:
[image]

```py
dfoutput = pd.DataFrame([["value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "null"],
                         ["value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value",
                             "value", "null", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "null", "value"],
                         ["value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value",
                             "value", "value", "null", "value", "value", "value", "null", "null", "value"],
                         ["value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value",
                             "value", "value", "value", "null", "value", "null", "value", "value", "value"],
                         ["value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "null", "value", "value", "value", "value"]],
                        index=['79876081-099b-474f-9e8f-ff917fd7394c', 'a96bc7cb-02b1-4d13-823a-908531cda095',
                               '38bc7d20-10be-4774-973c-b3b00234a645', 'e7b12da6-a47f-4c24-8545-faa24e249a03', '6b2c9426-bd6f-4bda-9c53-a86200e051f8'],
                        columns=['variable 1', 'variable 2', 'variable 3', 'variable 4', 'variable 5', 'variable 6', 'variable 7', 'variable 8', 'variable 9', 'variable 10', 'variable A', 'variable B', 'variable C', 'variable D', 'Variable E', 'Variable F', 'Variable G', 'Variable H'])
```

I did try to loop the columns and create a new dataframe, but got stuck and think I make it unnecessary complex.
I can't get my head around it. Someone dealt with this before? and have a useful direction for me to go?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: if you just have 5 datasets, this is quick in excel. stack the data sets one over the other and add an additional column for uuid. then run a pivot and you will get the same output. If this is a regular process and you want to automate it, then you can write a python script to read in each dataset and union them all and then use groupby to get this output. But if this is a one off task, i would just quickly get it over with in excel

Comment: @jezrael I did update my question with  df  with ceverted json data. Apologies to everyone for posting only images.

Comment: @Syed the amount of columns are variable some sets have more than 500 columns, so stacking them in excel is not the way to go for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-structure your data to your desired outcome with a rather simple manipulation. Note that I am using the `dataframe` (dfinput) you posted:

```
# Change first row to headers and Transpose
headers = dfinput.iloc[0]
one  = (pd.DataFrame(dfinput.values[1:], columns=headers)).T

# Change first row to headers again
one.columns = one.iloc[0]

# Keep only odd indexed rows
res = one.iloc[1::2, :]
```

---

```
res

uuid                                 variable 1 variable 2 variable 3 variable 4 variable 5 variable 6 variable 7 variable 8 variable 9 variable 10 variable A variable B variable C variable D Variable E Variable F Variable G
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
79876081-099b-474f-9e8f-ff917fd7394c      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value       value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value
a96bc7cb-02b1-4d13-823a-908531cda095      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value       value      value      value      value      value      value      value           
38bc7d20-10be-4774-973c-b3b00234a645      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value       value      value      value      value      value      value                      
e7b12da6-a47f-4c24-8545-faa24e249a03      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value       value      value      value      value      value      value      value           
6b2c9426-bd6f-4bda-9c53-a86200e051f8      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value       value      value      value      value      value      value      value      value
```